# What are the biggest problems with the winds/currents/biomes in my world?

Tags: magic, climate, geography, weather

Here's my map:

[image: Biome Map]

Red and blue arrows are major ocean currents, red representing warm ones and blue cool ones. Black arrows are prevailing winds. Hopefully everything else is self-explanatory! My planet does spin the opposite direction of Earth.

I'm doing a very top down approach with my worldbuilding, and this is my attempt to simulate climate based on where it seemed like ocean currents and winds would be located. I started with landmasses and what a few regions of the world would probably be like, then I made a plate tectonics map based on where I thought I wanted mountains to be, used that to inform other mountains and island chains, and from there I've fleshed out this biome map. I want to get feedback and correct all the glaring flaws before I delve too deeply into developing any specific area closely or fleshing out any additional cultures, though I do have a pretty good idea of what at least some of the people in most of the regions of the world are living like.

This map was mostly designed to hit the big, broad biomes. I know there are a lot of local nuances but I haven't gotten that far yet, I want to make sure the broad strokes look good first. But I am open to any suggestions on how local microbiomes might look!

Feel free to suggest exotic, fantasy climates, and any additional suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Am I reading your map right that you've got at least two prevailing winds right across mountain ranges, in the northwest and in the west around 30°N ±15°?

Comment: Welcome to the site Arha.  This questions is currently really broad.  Can you narrow it down to a specific question.  For example if the question is narrowed to "do the major currents and prevailing winds make sense based on x, y, z?"  Where x, y and z are things about your world, for example the reversed rotation.

Comment: The hold is just to give you time to edit and reorganize the question, once we do that we can get it re-opened.  Check out the [help] and [tour] when you get a chance as well.

Comment: FWIW, polar wetlands and taiga at around 50°N seems strange. In our world, that's around the southern tip of mainland UK, or just about right where you find the border between the better part of continental US and Canada. Hardly polar climate there.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling as someone who lives in that area, I'd definitely say its not exactly polar around here.